# Cant edit worddocument after opening the addin

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js

Regarding my earlier question “Word addin doesn't work on word online” I have now an addin where I get the header and footer with ooxml, and they are added in the initalizing process Office.initalize = function (reason).

When I open the addin the header and footer is added. When I then try to input anything in the main body its only possible to input on one line. This is only a problem on Word online. Local klient - no problem.

Should also mention that if you open an existing template from OneDrive and then open the addin there is no problems with inputing text in document.

I wonder if there is anyone else that has had this problem or slightly similar, and what solution you came up with? Please look at the earlier question for code: [“Word addin doesn't work on word online”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786014/word-addin-doesnt-work-on-word-online)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'return' before Word.run

```
function addHeader() {
    return Word.run(function (context) {

        var sections = context.document.sections;
        context.load(sections, 'body/style');

        return context.sync().then(function () {

            var header = sections.items[0].getHeader("primary");
            var templateHeader = getHeaderFooter('/xml/simrisHeader.xml');
            header.insertOoxml(templateHeader, Word.InsertLocation.replace);

            return context.sync().then(function () {
                console.log("Added a header to the first section.");
            });
        });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {

        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
```

Use the below style to call addFooter and addHeader:

```
addFooter().then(function() {
    addHeader();
};
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks Jiajia! Had to do a Little change.                      addHeader().then(function () {
                    addFooter();
                })

Answer (score 0):

You mean that the AddFooter and AddHeader can be successful by calling InsertOoxml API in the initialize method when opening the addin. But the main body of the document can't be edited after opening the addin.

I think there might be something unsupported in the main body just like the cause of the similar question "Word addin doesn't work on word online."

You could provide the doc for me, and then I can verify the root cause.

Comment: Well, they load without any problems. You open a new document. At that Point you can edit the text in main body. When you then open the addin from ribbon you can actually write text for several lines IF you dont hit enter. When you hit enter the text dissapears. When you klick outside the area of the inputed text it appears again. You can actually write over the existing text again but the text is now one fontsize down =)! Weard!  At the Point of opening addin no document is loaded. From console:

Comment: HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding an authentic HTML5 doctype: "<! DOCTYPE html>".             and      



HTML1405: Invalid character: NULL (U + 0000). Zero characters can not be used.

Comment: I have verified and found the root cause of your question. It is that your manner of using our APIs is wrong.

Comment: You should modify your method, such as addHeader and addFooter.
Add 'return' before word.run.

Comment: Use the below style to call addHeader and addFooter:
addFooter().then(function() {
 addHeader();
};